# PySNMP MibNotFoundError - Not compiling MIB files

Tags: python-3.x, pysnmp

I need to compile local .mib files into a format that PySNMP can work with. According to the [documentation](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/faq/pass-custom-mib-to-manager.html), such files should be compiled automatically by PySNMP.

So far, it works with pre-compiled files that are installed with PySNMP, but not any local files. When I try to specify where my .mib files are located, I get this error:

```
pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError: CISCO-IETF-IPMROUTE-MIB compilation error(s): missingcaused by <class 'pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError'>: MIB file "CISCO-IETF-IPMROUTE-MIB.py[co]" not found in search path (DirMibSource('/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs'), DirMibSource('/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/instances'), DirMibSource('pysnmp_mibs'), DirMibSource('/root/.pysnmp/mibs'), DirMibSource('~/projects/nemo/MIBs'))
```

My code:

```
def find_name_type(oid, module):

    mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder()
    compiler.addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources = ['~/projects/mibs'])
    mibBuilder.addMibSources(builder.DirMibSource('~/projects/mibs'))
    mibBuilder.loadModules(module)
    mibView = view.MibViewController(mibBuilder)
    oid, label, suffix = mibView.getNodeName(oid)

    modName, symName, suffix = mibView.getNodeLocation(oid)
    mibNode, = mibBuilder.importSymbols(modName, symName)
    data_type = mibNode.syntax.__class__.__name__
    return label[-1], data_type
```

When input is e.g.

```
find_name_type((1,3,6,1,2,1,31,1,1,1,6), 'IF-MIB')
```

output is ifHCInOctets Counter64 because IF-MIB is already compiled. Any other .mib files are not compiled, so

```
find_name_type((1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 9, 10, 117, 1, 1, 2, 1, 17), 'CISCO-IETF-IPMROUTE-MIB')
```

raises the error above. Contents of ~/projects/mibs is:

```
CISCO-IETF-IPMROUTE-MIB.mib  
IF-MIB.mib
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that underlying `pysmi` does not expand ~ into username. So either try using absolute path to ASN.1 MIBs or expand that path yourself:

```
compiler.addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources = [os.path.expanduser('~/projects/mibs')])
```

If neither helps, try to enable pysmi debugging to see where it searches for ASN.1 MIBs:

```
from pysmi import debug

debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('all'))
```

Comment: Tried that, the name now expands. Still get the error. Logs:

    pysmi: compiling CISCO-IETF-IPMROUTE-MIB read from file:///root/projects/MIBs/CISCO-IETF-IPMROUTE-MIB.mib
    pysmi: compiling CISCO-IETF-IPMROUTE-MIB read from file:///root/projects/MIBs/CISCO-IETF-IPMROUTE-MIB.mib
    pysmi: error from <pysmi.codegen.pysnmp.PySnmpCodeGen object at 0x7fc77db8a080>: no module "CISCO-SMI" in symbolTable at MIB CISCO-IETF-IPMROUTE-MIB
    pysmi: error from <pysmi.codegen.pysnmp.PySnmpCodeGen object at 0x7fc77db8a080>: no module "CISCO-SMI" in symbolTable at MIB CISCO-IETF-IPMROUTE-MIB